# Setting UUID, major, minor ID of RadBeacon Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I would like to know how to set the UUID, major, minor IDs of [RadBeacon Dot](https://store.radiusnetworks.com/products/radbeacon-dot) BLE beacons programmatically. In other words, without using the [RadBeacon Config App](https://store.radiusnetworks.com/products/radbeacon-config), but rather using my own iOS code. The beacons are currently in iBeacon mode.